# Microphone problems Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, microphone

I have a quite fresh installation of Kubuntu but I can't make my microphone work properly. When I try to record something and listen to the result, what I hear is only noise such as a broken microphone. I think nothing is broken since my laptop is brand new (it is a lenovo notebook essential V145-15AST).
I tried to play with settings in `pavucontrol` and `alsamixer` with no luck. 
If it can help, these are the current settings: 
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

P.S. I didn't test the microphone with another operating system since this was a free dos laptop and Kubuntu is the first OS I installed.

Comment: You can try this: In settings you'll find volume for left and right microphones separately. Set one of them to zero. I had a similar problem with a Lenovo laptop. This solved it.

Comment: By settings, I mean pavucontrol.

Comment: @apadana I put screenshots of my pavucontrol and I can't see any setting for left and right microphone

Comment: In pavucontrol, click on the tab "Input Devices", then click on the icon of a lock.

Comment: Oh god I did not upload pavucontrol screenshots. My bad. Your method is working by the way. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey AlessioF! If you can answer your own question, please do so. It'll be helpful to the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who have the same problem, I solved it:
in `pavucontrol` click on the tab "Input Devices", then click on the icon of a lock.  You'll find the volume for left and right microphones separately. Set one of them to zero